# How to call a Bigquery stored procedure in Nifi

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-nifi

I have a bigquery stored procedures which will run on some GCS object and do magic out of it. The procedures work perfect manually but I want to call the procedure from Nifi. I have worked with HANA and know that I need JDBC driver to connect and perform query.

Either I can use the executeprocess processor or I could use executeSQL processor. I dont know to be honest

I am not sure how to achieve that in Nifi with bigquery stored procedures. Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!!

Updated with new error if someone could help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option1: Executeprocess

The closest thing to "execute manually" is installing the Google Cloud SDK and execute within 'executeprocess' this:

```
bq query 'CALL STORED_PROCEDURE(ARGS)'
```

or

```
bq query 'SELECT STORED_PROCEDURE(ARGS)'
```

#### Option 2: ExecuteSQL

If you want to use ExecuteSQL with Nifi to call the stored procedure, you'll the [BigQuery JDBC Driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers).

Both 'select' and 'call' methods will work with BigQuery.

#### Which option is better?

I believe ExecuteSQL is easier than Executeprocess.

Why? because you need to install the GCloud SDK on all systems that might run executecommand, *and* you must pass the google cloud credentials to them.
That means sharing the job is not easy.

Plus, this might involve administrator rights in all the machines.

In the ExecuteSQL case you'll need to:

1 - Copy the jdbc driver to the `lib` directory inside your Nifi installation

2 - Connect to BigQuery using pre-generated access/refresh tokens - see [JDBC Driver for Google BigQuery Install and Configuration guide](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/jdbc/Simba%20JDBC%20Driver%20for%20Google%20BigQuery%20Install%20and%20Configuration%20Guide.pdf) - that's Oauth type 2.

The good part is that when you export the flow, the credentials are embedded on it: no need to mess with credentials.json files etc (this could be also bad from a security standpoint).

Distributing jdbc jars is easier than installing the GCloud SDK: just drop a file on the lib folder. If you need it in more than one node, you can scp/sftp it, or distribute it with Ambari.

Comment: really appreciate your answer. I will try to follow your guide with the executeSQL. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I tried with the second option you suggested. I gave the client id and client secret to DBCPoolConnection. Since my vm is headless (GUI less) it is trying to run xdg-open to get access token. Is there something I am doing wrong? here is my database url: jdbc:googlebigquery:ProjectId="projectid";DatasetId="datasetid";AuthScheme="OAuth";InitiateOAuth="GETANDREFRESH";OAuthClientId="clientid";OAuthClientSecret="clientsecret";

Comment: It is trying to open a web browser to start OAUTH - try adding OAuthType=2 to the jdbc connection string and use pre-generated access and refresh tokens (see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 )